# MongoDB query "OR" operator using parameter passed from JSP

Tags: java, mongodb, jsp, servlets, mongodb-query

In my project, I pass a parameter from JSP to servlet and receive it as :

```
String name= request.getParameter("name");
```

I successfully used the following query to search for a record in the collection using the name field like below:

```
List<Document> names= collection.find(eq("name", name)).into(new ArrayList<Document>());
```

My next step is to take any field(name, address, age) from the user in JSP and search for the record in mongodb having that field(entered by the user) and display the result. For this I unsuccessfully tried using:

```
 List<Document> names= collection.find(or("name", name),("address", name),("age", name)).into(new ArrayList<Document>());
```

Where "name" is the parameter that is passed from JSP.

I would like to know how can I modify the above query so that whatever(name, addrress,age) the user enters, the query searches for that record and returns the result for me.
In the above query where I tried using "or" it doesn't take "name" parameter multiple times. I wonder about the syntax that I have been using in the query. And even"or" doesn't seem to work unlike "eq".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please mention the Driver you are using in JSP.

Comment: @CS_noob Well I know that I have included Mongodb3.0.2 driver in the jar files that I have been working. Could you please tell me in detail since I am new in mongodb and self learning.
Thanks for prompt reply

Comment: Please if possible add the code that is above `List<Document> names= collection.find(eq("name", name)).into(new ArrayList<Document>());`
We will know what are types of objects of collection etc.

Comment: @CS_noob
I get the following result from the query:
List<Document> names= collection.find(eq("name", name)).into(new ArrayList<Document>());


[
    Document {
        {_id=59d25b1e41affc3dbc3b47c4, name=John, address=Baker Street}
    }, 
    Document {
        {_id=59d2a67541affc33ccc98a0b, name=John, address=Baker Street}
    }
]

Answer (score 0):

### Mistakes

1) It won't be compiled, since `or` requires several `com.mongodb.client.model.Filters` as arguments, for example several `eq` clauses within single `or`
2) `name` variable is used to filter `address` and `age` fields, you should use corresponding request parameter instead. Otherwise you won't get correct results.

### Correct code

```
String name = request.getParameter("name");
String address = request.getParameter("address");
String age = request.getParameter("age");


List<Document> names = collection.find(or(eq("name", name), eq("address", address), eq("age", age))).into(new ArrayList<Document>());
```

### Full working usage

Tested on Java 8 + MongoDB 3.4 with mongodb-driver v3.5.0 (using hardcoded values instead of parsing jsp request object):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import com.mongodb.*;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import org.bson.Document;

import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            // Dummy connection
            MongoClient client = new MongoClient();
            MongoDatabase database = client.getDatabase("stackoverflow_test_db");
            MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("stackoverflow_test_col");

            // Dummy data
            collection.insertMany(Arrays.asList(
                    Document.parse("{name:'name-1', address:'address-1', age:'age-1'}"),
                    Document.parse("{name:'name-2', address:'address-2', age:'age-2'}"),
                    Document.parse("{name:'name-3', address:'address-3', age:'age-3'}"),
                    Document.parse("{name:'name-4', address:'address-4', age:'age-4'}"),
                    Document.parse("{name:'name-5', address:'address-5', age:'age-5'}")
            ));

            // Hardcoded filters. Pretend like we got this with request.getParameter
            String name = "name-1";
            String address = "address-3";
            String age = "age-4";

            // Lookup
            List<Document> names= collection.find(or(
                eq("name", name), 
                eq("address", address),
                eq("age", age))).into(new ArrayList<>());

            // Print results
            names.forEach(System.out::println);

            // Clear storage
            collection.drop();
        } catch (MongoException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

### Output

> Document{{_id=59de7992bb63df2984a4d4a2, name=name-1, address=address-1, age=age-1}}
>   Document{{_id=59de7992bb63df2984a4d4a4, name=name-3, address=address-3, age=age-3}}
>   Document{{_id=59de7992bb63df2984a4d4a5, name=name-4, address=address-4, age=age-4}}

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this: `request.getParameter("name")` could contain any of `name`, `address` or `age` (and hence the need to apply a single 'OR'ed query) the following will work.

Assuming your colleciton has the following documents:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59de76eddcc75598230985eb"),
    "name" : "John",
    "address" : "Baker Street",
    "age" : 54
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59de770bdcc75598230985ec"),
    "name" : "Joe",
    "address" : "Main Street",
    "age" : 48
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59de771adcc75598230985ef"),
    "name" : "Jane",
    "address" : "Baker Street",
    "age" : 54
}
```

The following code will return the documents you expect (I think!):

```
String parameterValue = "John";
Bson filter = Filters.or(Filters.eq("name", parameterValue), Filters.eq("address", parameterValue), Filters.eq("age", parameterValue));
FindIterable<Document> documents = collection.find(filter);

for (Document d : documents) {
    // displays:
    //  { "_id" : { "$oid" : "59de76eddcc75598230985eb" }, "name" : "John", "address" : "Baker Street", "age" : 54 }
    logger.info(d.toJson());
}

parameterValue = "Baker Street";
filter = Filters.or(Filters.eq("name", parameterValue), Filters.eq("address", parameterValue), Filters.eq("age", parameterValue));
documents = collection.find(filter);

for (Document d : documents) {
    // displays:
    //  { "_id" : { "$oid" : "59de76eddcc75598230985eb" }, "name" : "John", "address" : "Baker Street", "age" : 54 }
    //  { "_id" : { "$oid" : "59de771adcc75598230985ef" }, "name" : "Jane", "address" : "Baker Street", "age" : 54 }
    logger.info(d.toJson());
}

parameterValue = "48";
filter = Filters.or(Filters.eq("name", parameterValue), Filters.eq("address", parameterValue), Filters.eq("age", Integer.valueOf(parameterValue)));
documents = collection.find(filter);

for (Document d : documents) {
    // displays:
    //  { "_id" : { "$oid" : "59de770bdcc75598230985ec" }, "name" : "Joe", "address" : "Main Street", "age" : 48 }
    logger.info(d.toJson());
}
```

The key point is that the structure of a ORed query looks like this:

```
Filters.or(condition, condition, ...)
```

For example:

```
Filters.or(Filters.eq("name", parameterValue), Filters.eq("address", parameterValue), Filters.eq("age", parameterValue))
```